# Convert a non-null terminated vector<char> to string

Tags: c++, string, vector, constructor, constructor-overloading

I have a non-null terminated vector of chars, how can I construct a new string and have it automatically insert `\0` to the end of string?

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.push_back('H');
v.push_back('i');
v.push_back('!');
//v.push_back('\0'); <~ without using this line

std::string a(v.data());
std::string b(v.begin(), v.end()); // same meaning as b(v.data(), v.size())
```

What is the correct constructor between the two?

Comment: When you are using `std::string` the terminating zero is automatically handled. However you would need it for the constructor of `a` because `std::string` will be looking for it while copying. You best bet would be to stick with the `b` constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::string a(v.data());` is not correct.  The constructor expects a pointer to a null terminated character sequence.  Not giving it one is undefined behavior.

`std::string b(v.begin(), v.end());` on the other hand is completely safe and will give you a `std::string` with the same content as the vector.

Answer (score 5):

This constructor:

```
std::string a(v.data());
```

expects that the argument is a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated C-style string. As `v.data()` does not point to a string that is null-terminated, this constructor call has undefined behavior.

You could add one more argument to make the constructor call valid:

```
std::string a(v.data(), v.size());
```

That is, instead of using this constructor:

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

you could use this constructor:

```
basic_string(const charT* s, size_type n, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

In this case, the string will be built exactly from `v.size()` characters stored in the vector.

This constructor:

```
std::string b(v.begin(), v.end());
```

is valid, and in fact is another form to supply a range without a null terminator, compared with the previous constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt will fail; std::string can be constructed from a null terminated array of chars, but without the null character the constructor will keep reading memory that the vector doesn't own until it finds a null byte.

Your second attempt is the solution; std:;string will copy the chars from the iterators and add the terminating null character automatically.